# Ajax call in ReactJS to hit service in Play Scala not accepting POST request (Cross domain)

Tags: ajax, playframework, reactjs, cross-domain

I am trying to build an isomorphic app with ReactJS as my front-end application server with express and Play framework as my back-end technology in Scala.

The problem that I am facing is that I do ajax calls from ReactJS to hit my webservices served by Play. My GET requests are working well but I am not able to POST data and I get the following error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:7050/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

I am aware of the Ajax call cross domains (CORS) but I am not able to configure this correctly on the play server side.

I added the filters library in the dependencies in my build.sbt :

> libraryDependencies += filters

These two routes allow me to configure OPTIONS HTTP request :

> OPTIONS  /                           controllers.Application.options(path="")
>
> OPTIONS  /*path                      controllers.Application.options(path)

My global object is as follows :

```
object Global extends WithFilters(CorsFilter) {

// called when a route is found, but it was not possible to bind the request parameters
  override def onBadRequest (request: RequestHeader, error: String) = Future.successful(
BadRequest("Bad Request: " + error)
  )

}

object CorsFilter extends Filter {

  def apply (nextFilter: (RequestHeader) => Future[Result])(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
      result.withHeaders(HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN -> "*",
      HeaderNames.ALLOW -> "*",
      HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS -> "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
      HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS -> "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent"
     )
   }
 }
}
```

On the controller side, I am configuring the OPTIONS request like this :

```
  def options(path: String) = CorsAction {
     Action { request =>
     Ok.withHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*",
     "Allow" -> "*",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" -> "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
     "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" -> "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent")
     }
  }
```

And the Action processing the HTTP requests as follows :

```
// Adds the CORS header
case class CorsAction[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] {

  def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[Result] = {
    action(request).map(result => result.withHeaders(HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN -> "*",
    HeaderNames.ALLOW -> "*",
    HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS -> "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
    HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS -> "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent"
    ))
  }

  lazy val parser = action.parser
}
```

And finally, my AJAX calls would be done like so :

```
$.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:7050/users",
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'POST',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          crossDomain: true,
          data: {"email": this.state.email, "pwd": md5(this.state.pwd)},
          success: function(data) {
            this.setState({user: data});
          }.bind(this),
          error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error("POST users", status, err.toString());
          }.bind(this)
        });
```

The version I am working in Play is 2.3.8.

Thanks a lot in advance for helping me solve this issue.

Merry christmas to everyone.

Regards

Comment: can you post the exact request, and  response as shown by your browser for the OPTIONS call? Also why not just implement the CORS filter that comes with the Play framework? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/CorsFilter